# PCI Passthrough via OVMF; No Video Output

Tags: nvidia, kvm, qemu, pci-passthrough

I've been following the Official Arch Linux Guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) and everything has been working exactly how it should be, but once I start the VM the Monitor connected to my GPU gets grey (Before that It was showing the MSI Logo, so it detected something was happening) but nothing more happens. I have QEMU open on the second Monitor and I can see the output on the preview but not on the actual Display. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3070 Ti

CPU: i9-12900k (Using the iGPU for Manjaro)

Answer (score 0):

It was an easy fix, I just had to add video=efifb:off to the grub config.